# Add additional boot option to Grub for X32 extensions?

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I work with a free/open source project. A Debian maintainer reported a failure under X32 (not a typo; its not X86), and I'm trying to set up a test environment to reproduce it.

According Debian's [X32 Ports wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/X32Port), I need to enable the X32 extensions in the kernel. To do that, I need to add the Grub entry. Below is what I added to `/etc/default/grub`, and its taken from the wiki page (except I commented the default entry).

```
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="syscall.x32=y quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="syscall.x32=y"
```

I then performed an `update-grub` per the wiki page and verified the entries in the compiled menu (see below).

When I boot the system, the option does not appear to be available under the main menu or the advanced options:

[image: Missing Grub entry for X32]

Debian's [Grub2](http://wiki.debian.org/Grub2) docs leaves a lot to be desired. It only discusses how to colorize menu entries (you can't make this sort of stuff up...).

I expected the following after following the prescription provided by the docs:

- Debian GNU/Linux
- Debian GNU/Linux (X32)
- Advanced options
- Memory test (memtest86+)
- Memory test (memtest86+, serial)
- ...

How do I add X32 boot options to Grub, give it a name like "Debian GNU/Linux (X32)", ensure its a boot option for the kernel during boot, and ensure the changes survive after an `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`?

---

According to Marius's answer below, I added the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux (X32)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os
  $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-a4af7dfc-640c-4aa8-bf0b-068af3d72b01' {
    linux/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-1-amd64 root=UUID=a4af7dfc-640c-4aa8-bf0b-068af3d72b01 ro syscall.x32=y quiet
}
```

It provides the named entry as expected, but it results in a boot error:

```
error: can't find command: `linux/boot/vmlinuz-4`
```

I think that was due to copy/paste in Emacs (it apparently removes whitespace???). So I changed it to `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-1-amd64...`. It resulted in a kernel panic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add `foo=bar` at grub

From a terminal run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and enter your password.

Find the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append foo=bar to its end. For example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash foo=bar"
```

Save the file and close the editor.

Finally, start a terminal and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to update GRUB's configuration file (you probably need to enter your password).

On the next reboot, the kernel should be started with the boot parameter

Source : Grub forums

Comment: Thanks BlueBerry. I set up a second VM with the `syscall.x32=y` option always in effect. The [Debian docs on GRUB](https://wiki.debian.org/Grub) don't tell us how to add a second, persistent entry with different options from the default ones. Can you tell me how to add a second, persistent entry that survives GRUB updates (i.e., when `/etc/default/grub` gets over written by the distro)? If so, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you right, you want to find a way to choose whether to boot with/out X32. You can do it in two distinct ways:

1. As need arises. Boot, at the boot menu hit <kbd>e</kbd> for `edit`, scroll down to the line

   ```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff quiet splash
   ```

and modify it to

```
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff syscall.x32=y quiet
```

Now continue booting.

2. Systematically. In the directory `/etc/grub.d/` there is an entry, `40_custom`, which is used exactly for this. You will have to copy in it a section of the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`: the part included between 
   `menuentry Debian GNU/Linux...` and the end of the breaces, <kbd>}</kbd>. 
   After inclusion, modify the line

   ```
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff quiet splash
   ```

into

```
     linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff syscall.x32=y quiet
```

Also, remember to change the name of the menuentry, in `40_custom` to something different from your first entry, otherwise you will not be able to distinguish the two entries.

Run `update-grub` and you are done.

Comment: Thanks Marius. *"...If I have understood you right..."* - here is what I am trying to do. They are the requirements phrased as a question: *"How do I add X32 boot options to Grub, give it a name like "Debian GNU/Linux (X32)", ensure its a boot option for the kernel during boot, and ensure the changes survive after an upgrade or dist-upgrade?"*

Comment: Well, I've been trying to figure out exactly must be copied from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and pasted into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. `grub.cfg` is very busy, each `menuentry` contains non-trivial scripting, and I'm not sure I am doing things correctly. Does Debian provide a clear and concise reference somewhere for this? I can't believe its this damn difficult...

Comment: @jww if you boot your machine, hit <kbd>e</kbd> when the Grub menu appears, you will find in front of you the standard menuentry that starts your system, without the fluff. That's the one you want to copy: pencil and paper...

Comment: Now I'm getting a kernel panic.... At this point, I think I am going to abandon this quest because I can't find clear and concise references or answers. I even asked on the Debian mailing lists (with no replies). There's no sense it continuing to aggravate myself, and I can create a second Debian 8 VM with `syscall.x32=y`. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the option just for the latest kernel in the top level menu, do not put "syscall.x32=y" in `/etc/default/grub`. Instead, find

```
linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" simple \
"${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}"
```

in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and add this after it:

```
linux_entry "${OS} (X32)" "${version}" simple \
"${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} syscall.x32=y"
```

Then run `update-grub` to update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` accordingly.

This way I could boot the latest kernel with "syscall.x32=y" option, but I don't notice difference to booting without it. That is in Xubuntu 15.10 64-bit. As for the configration surviving after grub package upgrade, I don't know; maybe installation notices a customized configuration file and gives you an option to keep it. At least this survives kernel updates.